# React rerender animation on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animate.css

i'm using **Animate css** in my project,  and i have a form where a user should provide an answer to a question.  If an answer is correct word  `correct` should be faded in and `wrong`  in opposite case. Here is a working simplified  example of my code.

**Stateful component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FormCheckIfCorrect from './FormCheckIfCorrect'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      correct: '5',
      userInput: '',
      userAnswer: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ userInput: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ userAnswer: '' }, () => {
      this.setState({ userAnswer: this.state.userInput })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>2 + 3 = ? </p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type='number' value={this.state.userInput} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button >Submit</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.userAnswer !== '' ? <FormCheckIfCorrect userAnswer={this.state.userAnswer} correct={this.state.correct} /> : ''}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Form
```

**Functional component:**

```
import React from 'react'

const FormCheckIfCorrect = (props) => {
  let result = props.userAnswer === props.correct ? <p className="animated fadeIn">correct</p> : <p className="animated fadeIn">wrong</p>
  return result
}

export default FormCheckIfCorrect
```

My question is about this part of my code :

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ userAnswer: '' }, () => {
      this.setState({ userAnswer: this.state.userInput })
    })
  }
```

In order to achieve the fade in effect each time a user clicks **Submit**  button i set `userAnswer` to nothing, and then in callback i set it again to `userInput`. 
It works(don't forget to include animate css), but i don't think it's a right way to do it. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your component **FormCheckIfCorrect**

```js
    const FormCheckIfCorrect = ({ userAnswer, correct }) => ( 
        <p className="animated fadeIn">
          { userAnswer === correct ? 'correct' : 'wrong' }
        </p>
    )
```

This way you don't repeat yourself by adding same p tags with duplicated class. Instead, we only change the content of the paragraph